# Allowing users to add arbitrary JavaScript in published articles

Tags: javascript, injection, secure-coding

It would be nice if sites like Medium or Substack allowed users to not only add text, images, code snippets, etc., but also custom scripts that allowed readers to run a little piece of code. For example, if someone was writing an article on how to create a unique react element, they could have the running code in the article, with interactive UI elements. Or perhaps adding a custom form to fill out.

What are the risks of allowing users to add arbitrary Javascript to hosted articles? Is it malicious code injection that’s the problem? Could a site like Medium guard against that somehow?

Comment: @mentallurg definitely related, although this question assumes service-side processing. For me, only client-side JS would be executable.

Comment: Stack Overflow does this by running the javascript in a sandboxed iframe